# How can I include JavaScript that use jQuery on admin side

Tags: admin, jquery, javascript, include

I try this:

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'custom_admin_scripts' ); 
function custom_admin_scripts() {   
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . /admin-scripts.js"></script>';
 }
```

but by this way it doesn't recognize jQuery. So I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.
I think that it because jQuery is linked after my script. As I see in HTML source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/wp-test/wp-content/themes/test/admin-scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/wp-test/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load=jquery,utils&amp;ver=edec3fab0cb6297ea474806db1895fa7"></script>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading your script before jQuery has been loaded.

**Do not print scripts directly**.

You should (register and then) enqueue them using the provided API. jQuery is already a registered script, so you can just enqueue it (say on the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook).

However you only need to load jQuery if you are loading a custom script that requires it, in which case you should enqueue your custom script and add jQuery as a dependency. WordPress will then handle the loading of the scripts and in the correct order:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','wptuts53021_load_admin_script');
function wptuts53021_load_admin_script( $hook ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'wptuts53021_script', //unique handle
        get_template_directory_uri().'/admin-scripts.js', //location
        array('jquery')  //dependencies
     );
}
```

#### Side remarks

- Use `get_template_directory_uri()` rather than `get_bloginfo()`
- Use the passed `$hook` (which will be `edit.php`, `post.php`, `post-new.php` etc) and [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to determine if you are on a page that requires your script to be loaded. Only load scripts when you actually need them.

E.g (Codex example):

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    //Load only on edit.php pages
    //You can use get_current_screen to check post type
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('/myscript.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's include them in a proper way.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_scripts' );

function custom_admin_scripts() {

  wp_register_script( 'admin-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

  if ( is_admin() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('admin-scripts');
  }

}
```

Second, take a read here http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes